# Can't verify ERC20/BEP20 token on BSCScan

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I deployed an ERC20/BEP20 token on binance smart chain using `truffle` and `openzepplin`. Now I want to verify this smart contract but I have some issues.

```
$ truffle run verify MyToken --network bsc

Verifying MyToken
Unable to process the standard-input-json you uploaded
Failed to verify 1 contract(s): MyToken
```

Let's try another way:

```
$ npx truffle-flattener ./contracts/MyToken.sol > ./contracts/token/FlatMyToken.sol

After copy/paste the output code into the bscscan I receive this error: 
ParserError: Multiple SPDX license identifiers found in source file. Use "AND" or "OR" to combine multiple licenses. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> myc
```

Using the second method, when I delete the relevant lines, the bytecode changes!

These methods do not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using https://github.com/hjubb/solt

Run:

```sh
solt write ./contracts/MyToken.sol
```

Then, once you've gotten the solc-input-MyToken.json file, you can upload it to BscScan directly.

The first method doesn't work because there's some weird issue with truffle verification, in that it doesn't submit valid JSON. The second method doesn't work because of the different SPDX identifiers. I have no idea why removing the spdx identifiers results in different bytecode, however.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I tried this way but the issue exists. screenshot: https://ibb.co/BqwckCn